# To show a function is 0 everywhere using an integral is 0

Tags: integration

The following problem is derived from another problem (more explicitly, I want to prove completeness of a sufficient statistic).

*Problem*:

> Let $M$ be a non-negative and absolutely continuous function over $(0, \theta)$ and differentiable everywhere. Let $k$ be a arbitrary function on the same domain. Also let $\mathcal{M}(x)$ be the integration of $M$ from $0$ upto $x$. $\mathcal{M}(\theta) = 1/Q(\theta)$ with $Q(\theta) > 0$. We have following equality for some $n > 1$, for $n$ in natural number:

$$\int_{0}^{\theta} (M(x))^{n-1}\mathcal{M}(x) k(x) dx = 0$$

We need to show $k$ is $0$ within the domain.

Can anyone give some idea how solve such generalised problem? Thanks.

Comment: If $M \equiv 0$ then $k$ can be any measurable function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy M is not 0, let me add that part.